# Working e2e UnitTests?

Tags: unit-testing

When I run e2e unit tests, it doesn't seem to recognise that I'm telling it to only use group e2e. This is possibly due to the default include/exclude filters in the phunit.xml file.

When I add the group e2e to the phunit.xml file, I get

CRM_BedResourceManager_BedResourceManagere2eTest
exception `RuntimeException` with message `\Civi\Test::e2e() requires a real CMS. Found CIVICRM_UF=UnitTests.`

When I hack the tools/scripts/phpunit to contain CIVICRM_UF='Drupal', not 'UnitTets' it then goes on to say

packages/DB/DataObject.php: "No database name / dsn found anywhere",

I tried popping some entries from civicrm_settings in there, but it didn't work.

a) Does anyone have a working e2e unit test config?

b) What are the settings I need to put in my tools/scripts/phpunit to make it work properly? My Civi and Drupes are in the same database.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by using the command `phpunit4` from inside the extension directory. Use `--group e2e` or `--group headless` as needed.